# How to cbind and rbind 2 lists of dataframes

Tags: r, rbind, cbind

I have 2 lists of dataframes. Each list has 24 dataframes

```
list1 <- (data1, data2, ..., data24)
list2 <- (result1, result2, ...., result3)
```

I want to `cbind` `data1` with `result1`, `data2` with `result2` and so on. Then `rbin`d all dataframes together like that:

```
all1 <- cbind(data1, result1)
all2 <- cbind(data2, result2)
all.in <- rbind(all1, all2)
```

How to do that efficiently with 24 dataframes?

Answer (score 7):

In tidyverse grammar, `dplyr::bind_rows` and `bind_cols` will bind a list together, and are invoked by `purrr::map_df` variants:

```r
library(tidyverse)

l1 <- list(mtcars[1:2, 1, drop = FALSE], mtcars[3:4, 1, drop = FALSE])
l2 <- list(mtcars[1:2, 2:6], mtcars[3:4, 2:6])

map2_dfr(l1, l2, bind_cols)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620
#> 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875
#> 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320
#> 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215
```

An `.id` parameter can be passed to both `bind_rows` and `map_dfr`, and will result in a new column with the name supplied consisting of an index for which list element each observation came from.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably do something like this:

```
l1 <- list(mtcars,mtcars)
l2 <- list(mtcars,mtcars)
do.call(rbind,mapply(FUN = cbind,l1,l2,SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

If the data frames are very large, you might switch to the dplyr or data.table equivalents of `cbind` and `rbind`.

Comment: instead of using `mapply` with `simplify=FALSE` why not use `Map`?

Comment: `do.call(rbind,Map(cbind,l1,l2))`

Comment: @Onyambu Because I’m old school, that’s why. ;)